# How to inflate a layout multiple times but with different data in its listview?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an xml layout that contains a listview. I would like to inflate the layout two times but the data of the listview is different in the second one. What happens here is the inflated layout is only 1 and it contains the second data set.

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ingredient,null);
    ingredientsView.addView(view);

    final IngredientAdapter ingredientAdapter = new IngredientAdapter(this, quantityArray, itemArray, remarksArray);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ingredientsList);
    listView.setAdapter(ingredientAdapter);



    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ingredient,null);
    ingredientsView.addView(view);

    final IngredientAdapter ingredientAdapter2 = new IngredientAdapter(this, quantityArray2, itemArray2, remarksArray2);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ingredientsList);
    listView.setAdapter(ingredientAdapter2);
```

Comment: Because you are passing the same datasource to the adapter 2nd time too.
Change the datasource which is getting assigned to your adapter in second call.

Comment: I have two of each sets, quantityArray and quantityArray2. is that what you meant? would you check the code again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in these combined lines of code:

> ```
> listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ingredientsList);
> listView.setAdapter(ingredientAdapter);
> ...
> listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ingredientsList);
> listView.setAdapter(ingredientAdapter2);
> ```

The `findViewById()` call will traverse your activity's view hierarchy starting from the top, and return the first view it finds with a matching id. So both of these `findViewById()` calls are returning the **first** ListView you inflated. Your program sets the first adapter and then sets the second adapter *to the same ListView* and you wind up only seeing the contents of the second adapter.

You can solve this by specifying which view to search inside of for `findViewById()` by calling the method on that view. So replace this second call:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ingredientsList);
```

with this instead:

```
listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ingredientsList);
```

Since `view` is your newly-inflated (second) layout, `view.findViewById()` will only search within that new layout.

Comment: thanks for the reply, the data did change to the first assignment but the layout still wasn't inflated.

Comment: @NicoDioso what type of view is `ingredientsView`?

Comment: @NicoDioso I expect what's happening is that the first inflated view is taking up all of the visible area on the screen, and the second is inflated and added but has 0 height... were you hoping that the two views would each get half of the available space?